# SQL Query to find ID's with as many hits as possible from an Array

Tags: php, sql, arrays

English is not my native language so i'll try to explain as good as i can.

I have a table with ID's in this table i also have account numbers.

something like this:

```
ID  ACCOUNT
1   1000
1   1001
1   1002
2   1000
2   1001
3   1003
```

then i have an array (Posted from a form, like name="array[0]",name="array[1]",name="array[2]"...) with these account numbers:

```
1000
1001
1002
1003
```

Now i want the query to get the ID's with the most "hits":

```
1 = 3 out of 4
2 = 2 out of 4
3 = 1 out of 4
```

so with this query i need to get:

```
1 for 1000, 1001 and 1002
3 for 1003
```

Kind off confusing? :)

Any suggestions?

Comment: I loose your train of thinking at your description of what you have in your array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT COUNT(`ID`) AS hits FROM table1 GROUP BY `ACCOUNT` WHERE ACCOUNT IN (1000, 1001, 1002) ORDER BY hits DESC